# Show toggling div based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have an anchor link, once clicked, show a div. I have a click toggle working on the page, but in addition to that functionality, if a user clicks a sidebar link, I don't want the div to toggle, I just want it to be shown, if hidden. I've tried several if thens, etc - I think this is the closest, but still not working.

Functions (first toggles the h4, the second is my attempt to have the same div shown if a URL is loaded...or the anchor link is clicked):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
$(".toggle_container3").hide();

//Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
$(".trigger3").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
}).first().click()

});
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#papers') > -1 ) {
    $("#papertoggle").show();
    $("h4#papers").addClass("active");
})
});

</script>
```

Also tried this version, with the keyword either "papers" or "climate_change_test#papers" :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Get URL
var url = window.location.href;
// Get DIV
var msg = document.getElementById('papertoggle');
// Check if URL contains the keyword
if( url.search( 'climate_change_test#papers' ) > 0 ) {
  // Display the message
  msg.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

HTML of the link:

```
 <li><a href="#papers" title="Research | Climate Change | Papers and Publications">Papers and Publications</a></li>
```

HTML of the h4 and div:

```
<h4 class="trigger3 dark_grey" id="papers">
<a href="#">Papers and Publications</a></h4>
<div class="toggle_container3" id="papertoggle"> content </div>
```

Entire test page:
http://www.sea.edu/sea_research/climate_change_test

Comment: Please note that it's a lot easier for us to debug your problem if you make a simplified version of it on http://jsfiddle.net/ or in a code snippet here. That way we know exactly which elements are important and which not, and we don't need to skip through a lot of unnecessary code. Additionally, if you do fix the issue on your live site, you still have a reproducable testcase here which can help future readers with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#over_left a").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $(id).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

However I would suggest to narrow down the `$("#over_left a")` selector so it only works on those specific submenu links.

---

> Also tried this version, with the keyword either "papers" or "climate_change_test#papers" :
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> // Get URL
> var url = window.location.href;
> // Get DIV
> var msg = document.getElementById('papertoggle');
> // Check if URL contains the keyword
> if( url.search( 'climate_change_test#papers' ) > 0 ) {
>   // Display the message
>   msg.style.display = "block";
> }
> </script>
> ```

The reason why the above code didn't work, is because it is executed on page load. However, when you click an anchor tag url, the page doesn't reload (it only jumps to the relevant anchor div), so this code is never executed.

Please also be aware that you don't need a complicated search to look for the "`#papers`" part in your url. You can simply use:

```
window.location.hash
```

To find the anchor part at the end of your url.

---

So combining all of the info from above, you can also create a function that deals with the following example: What if someone shares a link with an anchor url? It should automatically expand already then, right?

```
// On page load

var anchor = window.location.hash;
// If there is an anchor in the URL, expand the relevant div
if (anchor) {
    $(anchor).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
}
```

Comment: @SeaEdAssociation If I paste the first piece of code in my console on your page, it works. Are you sure you're implementing it correctly? Is the menu generated through Javascript perhaps?

Comment: Okay, yes, it was my implementation. The toggle is working. However, what I need is some check to see if the div is already open, so style="display:block;" then don't toggle. That is why I was trying to use .show() instead of toggle.

Comment: Trying to get the other function to work, so if someone shares the anchor that it will go to and expand that div. Does this get added to the over_left function or does it become its own function?

Comment: @SeaEdAssociation It's its own function, just like your piece of code I quoted. As for the toggle, you could check whether there is a `display: block;` style, but I would suggest the far more clean approach: using classes. Make a `.active` class on the div that you usually toggle, and then just `.addClass("active");` (it won't add it twice if it's already there). You can add css animations to make it slide smoothly.